# How can I atomically update number of first year students and put back to memcache?

Tags: google-app-engine

I am using memcahce in Google App Engine (Python SDK)to keep number of students per year, I am holding inside memcache dictionary like

```
{'first': 32, 'second': 23 }
```

How can I atomically update number of first year students and put back to memcache ?
I want ot increment when I put new model for student in datastore.
I tried like but it doesn't work ( I also tried add instead off put at the last line but it didn't work)

```
data = memcache.get('students')
if data is None:
    data = {}
data[student_year] = data.get(student_year, 0) + 1
memcache.set('students', data, 3600)
```

Comment: have you read the [incr() method](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/clientclass#Client_incr) ?

Comment: You do realize that storing this data is unreliable, and you could update a value, then a second later it has been purged.

Answer (score 2):

Store each number in the separate keys and use incr() as @presveva suggested.

```
memcache.incr(key='students_first', delta=1, initial_value=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comment memcache is unreliable and your values can be purged at any time (unless you are useing "dedicated memcache" service)

But for atomic updats to memcache values use Compare and Set

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/#Python_Using_compare_and_set_in_Python